# Sorting and enumerating imported data from txt file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys!

I'm trying to do a movie list, with data imported from a txt file that looks like this:

```
"Star Wars", "Y"
"Indiana Jones", "N"
"Pulp Fiction", "N"
"Fight Club", "Y"
```

(with Y = watched, and N = haven't seen yet)

I'm trying to sort the list by name, so that it'll look something like:

```
1. Fight Club (Watched)
2. Indiana Jones (Have Not Watched Yet)
3. Pulp Fiction (Have Not Watched Yet)
4. Star Wars (Watched)
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
def sortAlphabetically():
    movie_list = {}
    with open('movies.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            movie, watched = line.strip().split(',')
            movie_list[movie.strip()] = watched.strip()
            if watched.strip() == '"N"':
                print(movie.strip() + " (Have Not Watched Yet)")
            if watched.strip() == '"Y"':
                print(movie.strip() + " (Watched)")
```

I found a tutorial and tried adding this code within the function to sort them:

```
sortedByKeyDict = sorted(movie_list.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])
    return sortedByKeyDict
```

I also tried using `from ast import literal_eval` to try and remove the quotation marks and then inserting this in the function:

```
        for k, v in movie_list.items():
            movie_list[literal_eval(k)] = v
```

But neither worked.
What should I try next?
Is it possible to remove the quotation marks?
And how do I go about enumerating?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you can enumerate the file object that you are iterating over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, this should do it:

```
filename = './movies.txt'

watched_mapping = {
    'Y': 'Watched',
    'N': 'Have Not Watched Yet'
}

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

movies = []
for line in content:
    name, watched = line.strip().lstrip('"').rstrip('"').split('", "')
    movies.append({
        'name': name,
        'watched': watched
    })

sorted_movies = sorted(movies, key=lambda k: k['name'])

for i, movie in enumerate(sorted_movies, 1):
    print('{}. {} ({})'.format(
        i,
        movie['name'],
        watched_mapping[movie['watched']],
    ))
```

First we define `watched_mapping` which simply maps values in your file to values you want printed.

After that we open the file and read all of its lines into a `content` list.

Next thing to do is parse that list and extract values from it (from each line we must extract the movie name and whether it has been watched or not). We will save those values into another list of dictionaries, each containing the movie name and whether it has been watched.

Thats what `name, watched = line.strip().lstrip('"').rstrip('"').split('", "')` is for, it basically strips garbage from each end of the line and then splits the line by garbage in the middle, returning clean `name` and `watched`.

Next thing to do is sort the list by `name` value in each dictionary:

```
sorted_movies = sorted(movies, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

After that we simply enumerate the sorted list (starting at 1) and parse it to print out the desired output (using the watched_mapping to print out sentences instead of simple `Y` and `N`).

Output:

```
1. Fight Club (Watched)
2. Indiana Jones (Have Not Watched Yet)
3. Pulp Fiction (Have Not Watched Yet)
4. Star Wars (Watched)
```

Case insensitive sorting changes:

```
sorted_movies = sorted(movies, key=lambda k: k['name'].lower())
```

Simply change the value movies get sorted by into lowercase name. Now when sorting all the names are treated as lowercase.

Comment: Glad i could help :D

Comment: hi! quick question, is there any way to make it so that the items get sorted, it's non-case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Your function with some quick fix

```
def sortAlphabetically():
    movie_list = []
    with open('movies.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            movie, watched = line.strip().split(',')
            movie_list.append({
                'name': movie.strip()[1:-1],
                'watched': watched.strip()[1:-1]
            })
    return sorted(movie_list, key = lambda x : x['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I just modified your code. When you use `sorted()` on a `dictionary`, then dictionary gets converted to a `list of tuples`. All I have done is that I have made another `dictionary` from the existing `list of tuples`.

```py
def sortAlphabetically():
    movie_list = dict()
    with open('movies.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            movie, watched = line.strip().split(',')
            movie_list[movie.strip()] = watched.strip()

    movie_sorted = sorted(movie_list.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[0])
    movie_list = dict()
    for key, value in movie_sorted:
        movie_list[key] = value
    i = 1
    for key, value in movie_list.items():
        if value == 'Y':
            print("{}. {} {}".format(i,key,"(Watched)"))
        else:
            print("{}. {} {}".format(i,key,"Have Not Watched Yet"))
        i += 1
```

I intentionally kept the code simple for better understanding. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @reclusive_nymph glad I could help :)

Comment: hi! quick question, is there any way to make it so that the items get sorted, it's non-case sensitive?

Comment: @reclusive_nymph the solution which I have is case sensitive. I can make it non-case sensitive if you want

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: in place of `lambda kv: kv[0]` use `lambda kv: kv[0].lower()`

Comment: Glad could be of help :)